# Generate a google map using latitude and longitude code script

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I need to generate a google map with a marker.

I have the latitude and longitude code.

There's lots of scripts around but what is the quickest way to display the map on my web page using the latitude and longitude codes that I have?

This is the current code: - No map is being displayed

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
         var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
         var myOptions = {
             zoom: 4,
             center: myLatlng,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             }
          map = new google.maps.Map($('#map'), myOptions);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng, 
              map: map,
          title:"Fast marker"
         });
    }) 
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `$('#map')` is not an HTML Element, it is a JQuery array of elements, use `$('#map')[0]` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/936dww1o/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Markup**

```
<script language=javascript src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false'></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function initialize(){
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng, 
          map: map,
      title:"Fast marker"
     });
} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load', initialize);
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
     var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 4,
         center: myLatlng,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
      map = new google.maps.Map($('#map'), myOptions);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng, 
          map: map,
      title:"Fast marker"
     });
}
```

Comment: The code from here essentially: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#Markers

Comment: Trying your code but I must be missing something? I've added full code above

Comment: are you getting any errors? Do you add the libraries needed, check my update answer

Comment: Yeah, tested it but no map. I just need either javascript or jquery right?

Comment: Ditto what Jorge said.  Using identical code, but no map.  No error in the console.  I'm adding an alert() in the initialize function but it isn't being triggered.

Comment: I am facing the same problem.
No map on screen.

Comment: Add Style in Div Tag <div id="map" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></div>

Answer (score 2):

The code is adding some invisible content to the map div. To view it, we need to add CSS:

```
#map { width: 500px; height: 400px; }
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11106280)

Comment: Sorry but I don't have mandatory 50 reputation to add a comment. Anyways I have figured out the solution. We need to add CSS #map {
      width: 500px;
      height: 400px;
}