# how to display map in iframe having latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have two paramers (longitude and latitude) already saved in database ,
how to generate a maps (google) in an iframe using only html5 widhout jQuery or javascript

Comment: I think this was already answered here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886416/generate-a-google-map-using-latitude-and-longitude-code-script

Answer (score 0):

Google offers a "Static Maps API" which seems to cover everything you need:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

For example, a map centered on 40°N 70°W would look like:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40,-70&zoom=5&size=600x300

So you just put in the coordinates and give the address to your iframe. For the exact configuration, all other possible parameters are explained in the API documentation. The given example already uses "zoom" and "size".