# How To Add A Map For Every Product View Page

Tags: google-maps, magento

I have a coffee store based shop in magento . Now i want to show the map for each coffee shop in the product view

[image]

every store has its different location for google map. any help would be very thankful and appreciable. there are different store google map store extension but i want to show on the product page and each product has its different google map location how we can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a product attributes (**longitude** and **latitude**) and add that attribute to your attribute set. Once you did that, you will be able to set **longitude** and **latitude** for every product individually. Next step would be to create a custom part in **phtml** file that is reading these attributes (for example copy **catalog/product/view.phtml** in your theme) and add a part for embeded code where you pass **longitude** and **latitude** to generate map.

Be aware that attributes should have selected *Visible on product page* to *Yes* in order to be able to use them on product page using following code in *catalog/product/view.phtml*:

```
$this->getLatitude();
```

or

```
$this->getLongitude();
```

Instead of extending and copying *catalog/product/view.phtml* to your theme, the more correct way would be that you add a custom *phtml* file and include it with *xml* to render on the correct place, but that might be hard for you if you are not familiar with Magento structure.

Example how to get Google Map from longitude and latitude:

[Generate a google map using latitude and longitude code script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886416/generate-a-google-map-using-latitude-and-longitude-code-script)

Comment: can you please give me the example i want to put the code in view.phtml file please came up with a example so that it will be easier for me its confusing.

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra I have included a Google Map example code